# Capacitive load at the output for analysis of CMOS cells

Tags: cmos, output, load, capacitive

This question is very rudimentary one. Please point me to the link if this question has been already asked.

In general, when working with simulations and and analyzing the standard cells designed based on CMOS logic, a capacitive load is tied to the output of the cell or gate. Why is it not a resistive load but a capacitive one? The timing characteristics are measured after tying the output to a standard capacitive value. Wouldn't the delays measured during the simulations (e.g. using SPICE based tools) be affected due to the rise and fall times of the connected capacitor?

Edit: If the capacitive load seems a realistic option, wouldn't a RC combination be still simple and more realistic?

Comment: Maybe that's the whole point - it represents reality

Comment: @Andyaka please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors are used as test loads in CMOS logic because the *actual* load when connected to other logic (the gates of additional MOSFET transistors) is primarily capacitive.

Comment: yes. but purely capacitive? Why not an RC combination?

Comment: There is also impedance to be taken into account

Comment: Drain-source resistances of MOSFETs in the gate give the R in RC.

Comment: @SzymonBęczkowski: Yes, but that's modeled as part of the gate, not part of the load.

Comment: Merely, the point still maybe that using a single component might reduce complexity during measurements :/